# c++ program will not run correctly

Tags: c++

This is a cryptography program that is supposed t encrypt and decrypt a message using rot13 encryption. When I run the program it spits out a bunch of nonsense and then tells me the program has "stopped working."

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char lookup(bool, char);
class Cipher{
public:
    string encrypt(string);
    string decrypt(string);
};

string Cipher::encrypt(string text) {
    return text;
}

string Cipher::decrypt(string text) {
    return text;
}

class Rot13: public Cipher {
public:
    string encrypt(string);
    string decrypt(string);
};

string Rot13::encrypt(string text) {
    string modstring;
    for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
        modstring+=lookup(true,text[i]); 
    }
    return modstring;
}
string Rot13::decrypt(string text) {
    string modstring;
    for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
        modstring+=lookup(false,text[i]);
    }
    return modstring;
}
char lookup(bool b, char c) {
    string norm = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string rot13 = "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm";
    if (c==' ')
         return c;
    if(b){
        for(int i=0;i<52;i++) { 
            if(norm[i]==c)
                return rot13[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int i=0;i<52;i++) {
            if(rot13[i]==c)
                return norm[i];
        }
   }
}
string encrypt_with(Cipher *cipher, string text) {
    cipher->encrypt(text);
}

string decrypt_with(Cipher *cipher, string text) {
    cipher->decrypt(text);
}

int main(){
    string s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
    Rot13 *rot13;
    rot13 = new Rot13;
    string d = encrypt_with(rot13,s);
    string e = decrypt_with(rot13,d);
    cout << d << endl;
    cout << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions virtual in the base:

```
class Cipher{
public:
    virtual string encrypt(string);
    virtual string decrypt(string);
};
```

This is because they're called on the base class within `encrypt_with` and `decrypt_with` and so the base functions get called as they're not marked as virtual. I'd also recommend making them abstract as 'encrypting and decrypting on an instance of a base Cipher doesn't really make sense:

```
class Cipher{
public:
    virtual string encrypt(string) = 0;
    virtual string decrypt(string) = 0;
};
```

Incidentally, using a debugger would've found this very quickly - I'd recommend getting familiar with the debugger your tools setup comes with as its an indispensable skill to have

Theres another issue in the code which is that lookup doesn't return anything if the character wasn't found so you'll have garbage. You'll either want some error checking (throw an exception maybe?) or returning a known value.

EDIT: Also, as Leiaz pointed our encrypt_with and decrypt_with should return the values from their call to the cypher object:

```
string encrypt_with(Cipher *cipher, string text) {
    return cipher->encrypt(text);
}

string decrypt_with(Cipher *cipher, string text) {
    return cipher->decrypt(text);
}
```

Comment: A bigger problem is functions that should return a string are not returning anything.

Comment: @Leiaz Thus the garbage being returned.